# Array of Structurer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I was just brushing my pointer concepts and it seems its really messed up over time.

I was trying to implement BFS in binary tree.

Pseudo Code :

```
1) tempNode = root node
2) while tempNode is not null
       print data at tempNode
       enqueue left and right child
       tempNode = dequeue
```

Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_Q_SIZE 100
/**
 * Using Queue to keep track of next nodes to be visited
 */

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

struct node *createQueue(int *front, int *rear)
{
    struct node *queue = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node) * MAX_Q_SIZE);
    *front = *rear = 0;
    return queue;
}

void enQueue(struct node *queue, int *rear, struct node *newNode)
{
    queue[*rear].data = newNode->data;
    queue[*rear].left = newNode->left;
    queue[*rear].right = newNode->right;
    (*rear)++;
}

struct node *deQueue(struct node *queue, int *front)
{
    (*front)++;
    return &queue[*front - 1];
}

struct node *newNode(int data)
{
    struct node *node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

void printBFS(struct node *root)
{
    int front,rear;
    struct node *queue = createQueue(&front, &rear);
    struct node *tempNode = root;

    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",tempNode->data);

        if(tempNode->left != NULL)
            enQueue(queue,rear,tempNode->left);
        if(tempNode->right != NULL)
            enQueue(queue,rear,tempNode->right);
        tempNode = deQueue(queue,front);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = newNode(1);
    root->left = newNode(2);
    root->right = newNode(3);
    root->left->left = newNode(4);
    root->left->right = newNode(5);

    printBFS(root);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following 4 types of warnings :

```
BFS2.c: In function ‘printBFS’:
BFS2.c:60:13: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘enQueue’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
             enQueue(queue,rear,tempNode->left);
             ^
BFS2.c:23:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void enQueue(struct node *queue, int *rear, struct node *newNode)
      ^

BFS2.c:63:9: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘deQueue’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         tempNode = deQueue(queue,front);
         ^
BFS2.c:34:14: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 struct node *deQueue(struct node *queue, int *front)
```

Can anyone please help me to clarify the doubts as to why I am getting the warnings. I am unable to figure out the problems here. :(

Comment: Identify where lines please

Comment: Well the first error appears in `printBFS` where you have `int front,rear` but the second argument in enqueue should be `int*`--this i can deduce without knowing much about c except what a pointer is.

Comment: Don't cast the returned pointer from malloc.

Comment: As the answer points out, all the errors are a result of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate pointer problems come from attempting to pass an int as a pointer:

```
int front,rear;
    ...
        enQueue(queue,&rear,tempNode->left);
//         enQueue(queue,rear,tempNode->left);
```

You have the same issue with `deQueue` immediately following. However, you have larger issues to deal with. Once you fix the pointer issues you will be faced with a `Segmentation fault`..

And to not leave you hanging, you simply need to go back and rework your queue implementation, it is a wreck. You will generate a Segmentation fault because your value for `front` in `deQueue` grows unchecked until i reaches a value of `100` and you attempt to write beyond the end of your `MAX_Q_SIZE` block of memory.

If you are brushing up on pointers, then don't torture pointers to try and shoehorn them into array syntax. There is no need for passing `struct node *queue` and then attempting to find *array* index syntax that will work:

```
queue[*rear].right = newNode->right;
```

when a simple pointer expression will do:

```
(queue + *rear)->right = newNode->right;
```

The same applies to:

```
return (queue + *front - 1);  // syntax only your queue logic need fixing
```

This will make your code much more readable and reduce the chance for error when you pass pointers but then try and make the pointer work with something like:

```
return &queue[*front - 1];
```

Comment: You must love the sense of mystery :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Oh!!! I really made a stupid mistake by passing int as pointer and couldn't figure it out. Thanks. And for the `MAX_Q_SIZE`, I intentionally didn't check that because I just wanted to get the BFS of 5 node (hardcoded) tree and then a seg fault is fine for me. The focus was just the pointers, structures and pointer to array of structures.

Comment: Glad I could help. Generally passing variables as pointers has quite a few advantages. However, just like anything else, the rest of your code has to properly handle whatever you pass as an argument. You will find passing pointers (or the address of a pointer) is the only way to accomplish many tasks, such as declaring a pointer and passing it to a function for allocation.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `int` variables where `int*` (pointer to int) is expected. Pass the address of an `int` variable with `&` the *address of* operator. Multiple examples :

```
enQueue(queue, &rear, tempNode->left);

enQueue(queue, &rear, tempNode->right);

tempNode = deQueue(queue, &front);
```

As David has pointed out, the program will crash (segmentation fault). You may want to rethink the design of deQueue and/or what should happen if both `tempNode->left` and `tempNode->right` are `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing `front` and `rear` to `enQueue()` and `deQueue()`, pass `&front` and `&rear`. The `&` (address-of operator) takes the address of the variable. Since both `front` and `rear` are `int`s, this operator will create the correct result, an `int *`.

As an aside: [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).